# I don't want to show password when I register IRC freenode

Tags: emacs, passwords, irc

The enviroment is emacs 24.5+ Macpro 10.10.5

I can use `/msg nickserv register **** 1@1.com` to register, but I don't want to show the password even I can kill the buffer later.  How can I do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more details if you hope to get a more specific answer. For example, you have not stated which IRC client you are using in emacs and your request is not terribly clear. Where precisely are you worried about the password show? When you type it at the M-x prompt or are you typing in the whole command in the IRC uffer?

Assuming you are using ERC as your client, you can setup your config using the auth-sources library. To do this, you just need to create an authinfo.gpg file in your home directory with your credentials in it (following the standard netrc format). When you save the file, you will be prompted for a gpg password. The file will be kept encrypted on hour hard drive using gpg. The first time you try to access IRC, you will be prompted for your authinfo gpg password. Once you enter that, emacs will automatically decrypt the file, retrieve your IRC credentials and register your nick (you will need to set the erc-prompt-for-password variable to nil - use customize to do this).